# Switch from RabbitMQ to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq

How easy is to switch from Rabbit to Kafka in existing solution, to replace one implementation (Rabbit) with other (Kafka)? We are about to use Rabbit in our implementation but we want to see if it is possible in the future to replace it  with Kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, and I've seen people do it - but it is a big project.

Not only the APIs are different, but the semantics are different. So you need to rethink your data model, scaling model, error handling, etc. And then there's testing.

If you don't have tons of code to update, and the code is localized and you have both RabbitMQ and Kafka experts on the team you may be able to get it done in a month or two.

Comment: Thanks! It is really helpful!